# Pandas.DataFrame.sum(axis = 1) not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum my dataframe across axis = 1 but for some reason its not working for me. I'm not entirely sure why its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

**Original DataFrame:**

[image]

**Attempt at summing along axis = 1**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is problem `type` of your data is not `float` but `string`.

So need cast to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
norm = data[colors.keys()].astype(float).sum(axis=1)
```